# Populating a matrix with the values from array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following arrays,

```
Names = [string('abc') string('def') string('ghi') string('jkl')]
SubName1 = [string('abc') string('jkl')]
SubValue1 = [-1 1]
SubName2 = [string('ghi') string('jkl')]
SubValue2 = [-2 1]
```

The array named `SubValue1` contains the values that correspond to the keys(strings) in the array named `SubName1`.I want to compare `SubName` with `Names` and create a matrix that maps the key-value pair as follows

```
RowName  SubName1 SubName2
abc          -1       0
def           0       0 
ghi           0      -2
jkl           1       1
```

To obtain the above matrix I'm trying the following,

```
Index1 = find(ismember(Names,SubName1))
Index2 = find(ismember(Names,SubName2))

>>Index1 = [1 4];
>>Index2 = [3 4];
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Essentially, I am trying to fill the columns of the matrix with the values `SubValue` of the keys`SubNames` at the indices present in `Index`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Create empty vectors and use logical indexing with `Index1` and `Index2` to insert the values from `SubValue1` and `SubValue2`:

```
>> Names = [string('abc') string('def') string('ghi') string('jkl')];
>> SubName1 = [string('abc') string('jkl')];
>> SubValue1 = [-1 1];
>> SubName2 = [string('ghi') string('jkl')];
>> SubValue2 = [-2 1];

>> Index1 = find(ismember(Names,SubName1))
>> Index2 = find(ismember(Names,SubName2))

>> SubName1 = zeros(numel(Names),1);
>> SubName2 = zeros(numel(Names),1);

>> SubName1(Index1) = SubValue1;
>> SubName2(Index2) = SubValue2;

>> t = table(Names.',SubName1,SubName2);
>> t.Properties.VariableNames(1) = {'RowName'}

t =

  4×3 table

    RowName    SubName1    SubName2
    _______    ________    ________

     "abc"        -1           0   
     "def"         0           0   
     "ghi"         0          -2   
     "jkl"         1           1
```

---

Note that the practice of naming variables such as `SubName1` and `SubName2` is generally discouraged. You mind find [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) MATLAB answers post useful.